# Why is local-m Attention differentiable?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent, attention

In this paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.04025.pdf) local attention is introduced. With local-m attention, we compute the attention vector over the source hidden states within a window around the fixed center $p_t$. This is the same as 'multiplying' the source state sequence with a $rect$-function. And the $rect$-function is not differentiable, however, the authors claim that their model is.

How is this possible?

If this is the case, then why don't we implement hard attention (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03044.pdf) the same way: predict the position $p_t$ with a feed-forward net, instead of sampling, and then just use a window of size 1. This way we can use normal backpropagation and don't need reinforcement learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rect is differentiable in the same way that convolution is differentiable. Even though it assigns 0 weight to all inputs outside of the rectangular window -- in the same way that a convolutional filter assigns 0 weight to all inputs outside of it's receptive field -- the window is slid over the entire range of inputs, so every input contributes to the output.

Hard-attention is differentiable with respect to the inputs to the attention mechanism, but non-differentiable with respect to the *parameters inside the attention mechanism*. local-m attention does not have this problem, because it does not predict the alignment as a hard-attention mechanism does. Instead local-m attention assumes the input is already perfectly aligned with the output. local-m attention does not predict the position $p_t$. The authors write... "$p_t=t$".

It's worth noting that the other attention model in the paper, local-p attention, is a soft mechanism.

Comment: Pardon me, but why do we need the Gaussian functon with local-p attention if $rect$ is differentiable? Is it because local-p is a soft mechanism (= attend to all input locations) and we therefore need to consider positions where the gradient of $rect$ is not defined (at the step from 1 to 0 and vice versa)?

Comment: rect is differentiable with respect to the inputs, but not with respect to the *position of the window*.

Comment: this is not a problem in local-m because there, the position is not learned (we assume it's perfectly aligned). not so with local-p.

Comment: '$rect$ is differentiable with respect to the inputs, but not with respect to the position of the window.` Can you elaborate on this? Lets say we have $rect(x−p_t)$ with a width of $L$. 1. Does `with respect to the inputs` mean we derive only in the interval of $L$ where the derivative is 0? 2. How do we even derive `with respect to the position` $p_t$? I mean I just use $p_t$ in the definition of rect with case differentiation.